# Creating a dynamic autofill range in recorded code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a dynamic range in a recorded macro.
The data in column "O" is variable.
When I used the macro, VBA set it at the range of the specific worksheet.
Is there a way to make the autofill option variable to the amount of rows?

I used this code:

```
Range("O2").Select

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O188")

Range("O2:O188").Select
```

I want the range to be dynamic.

Comment: When you say 'to the amount of rows', what do you mean? For instance, the rows of the column N:N will be good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please. It uses column N:N as reference for the number of rows to be filled. No need to select anything:

```
Sub testAutoFill()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  sh.Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range("O2:O" & lastRow)
End Sub
```

The code can use the maximum rows of the used range, but in such a case, if the value to be filled down is a formula, the referenced column is good to be used. Otherwise, one of the neighbor column.

Comment: @Franco: Did you test the above code? Do you have an answer to the question regarding which reference column to be used to determine the last row to be filled?

Comment: @Franco: Still alive?

Comment: apologies for the late reply, holiday season. It worked! Thank you very much!